# What happens to schema objects when you DROP USER but don't specify CASCADE?

Tags: sql, oracle, security, privileges

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9008.htm) for `DROP USER` states: 
"Oracle Database does not drop users whose schemas contain objects unless you specify `CASCADE`".

My understanding is that all schemas must have an associated user account (though that account can be restricted from use by restricting `CREATE SESSION` command, etc...). But what actually happens to previously owned objects when you use the `DROP USER` command? If the user no longer exists... then what account owns those objects?

**For Context**, I'm a developer not a DBA and don't have DCL rights on my databases so I can't test this out myself. I am working a migration project where this command may be necessary but I'd like to better understand the implications before passing a request along to my Enterprise DBA team.

Comment: Doesn't DROP without CASCADE fail if the user has objects.

Comment: Isn't that what the statement you quoted says? It doesn't (won't) drop users with objects if you don't specify cascade. You can't have orphan objects. Also note that if you drop a user their recycle bin is purged; so if you drop cascade then the user's objects are permanently deleted and don't go in the recycle bin either.

Comment: @Alex Poole - Yeah.... definitely read that wrong the first time. I thought the documentation was saying that it won't take care of the corresponding objects unless you specify cascade. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempt to drop a user (e.g. THE_USER) without specifying CASCADE you will get the following error:

```
ORA-01922: CASCADE must be specified to drop 'THE_USER'
```

Either use the `CASCADE` option with your `DROP USER` statement or manually remove all user objects before dropping the user.

HTH

Comment: Thanks... I had misread the documentation and didn't realize they were saying that the operation would fail entirely if a user has objects but cascade is not specified. Thanks for clearing that up.